# knitr with bash: change working directory

Tags: r, bash, markdown, knitr, cd

I am using knitr for making a markdown report for some bash commands. However, my operations include changing a directory and creating a file there, so it would be ideal if I could use `cd` in my .Rmd file:

````
make a directory
```{r mkdir, engine='bash'}
mkdir mytest
```
cd into directory
```{r cd, engine='bash'}
cd mytest
```
create file
```{r create, engine='bash'}
touch myfile
```
check contents
```{r ls, engine='bash'}
ls
```
````

However, the file `myfile` is created in the directory from which I compile the document with `knit` and not in `mytest`. I guess a new bash shell is started for each code chunk.

I have seen discussions about setting `cwd` in R    (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/277) but not for bash.

Is there a way of maybe setting a working directory for a code chunk?

Comment: Did you take a look at `opts_knit$set(root.dir = "...")` and `setwd("...")`?

Comment: Yes, but these are both R functions and I do not have any R code in my chunks. I am only using R to call `knit`. So I do not see a possibility to change cwd between chunks...

Comment: That is a known problem. Please see the last paragraph of http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/ Also see https://github.com/yihui/runr I'm not quite sure if runr still works well in terms of the `bash` engine.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at runr

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Rscript` to run a `.Rmd` file and include any "R code" within the command line to keep your code chunks intact.

`Rscript -e "library(knitr); opts_knit\$set(root.dir='~'); knit('test.Rmd')"` is an example bash command to run the `test.Rmd` file below. You may change the `root.dir` to suit your needs.

````
make directories
```{r mkdir, engine='bash'}
mkdir mytest
mkdir mytest2
```

create one file in the 1st dir
```{r create, engine='bash'}
cd mytest
touch myfile
```

create another file in the 2nd dir
```{r create2, engine='bash'}
cd mytest2
touch myfile2
```

check contents
```{r ls, engine='bash'}
ls mytest*
```
````

The output:

````
```
## mytest:
## myfile
##
## mytest2:
## myfile2
```
````

Comment: he root.dir set in the options here has no effect; your solution creates the files within the created directories because `cd` and `touch` are in the same code chunk.

Comment: I see same problem you mention, @user1981275.  the dir never changes, everything stays in document directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at it would be to create every folder and file from where you are, and not move around with cd.

## Create a directory tree

mkdir accepts more than one argument

```
mkdir -p 'plots/scatter' 'plots/box'
# creates plots folder in the working directory,
# and then creates scatter and box folders in it.
```

## Create files in there

```
touch 'plots/scatter/firstfile.txt' 'plots/scatter/secondfile.txt'
# single quotes mean literals
```

## Keep key parts as variables

To easily change the folder structure from a one central variable:

```
scatter_folder=plots/scatter
touch "$scatter_folder/third_file.txt" "$scatter_folder/fourth_file.txt"
# double quotes allow for variable substitution.
```